# Is there a way to use Vanta.js effects in a Nuxt.js project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently making a personal portfolio site using Nuxt.js (using TypeScript).
I decided I want to use [Vanta.js Halo effect.](https://www.vantajs.com/?effect=halo) for my landing page, but I can't seem to find a way to make it work properly.

I tried using three.js and vanta npm packages, but it produces an error.
'Cannot read property “texture” of undefined'

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import HALO from 'vanta/dist/vanta.halo.min.js'

...

*inside Vue.extend block*
mounted(){
    this.vantaEffect = HALO({
    el: '#landing',
    *rest of the settings*
    THREE: THREE
    })
}
```

Is there any way I can make it work?

Update:

I managed to get rid of the errors using static files - method from [this vanta repo issue](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/issues/18), but static script for initiating can't find the #landing element.

```
/*nuxt.config.js*/

...
head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || '',
      },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
    script: [
      { src: 'vanta.halo.min.js' },
      { src: 'three.min.js' },
      { src: 'effect.js' },
    ],
  },
...
```

```
/*effect.js - file that initializes the effect*/
VANTA.HALO({
  el: '#landing',
  mouseControls: true,
  touchControls: true,
  gyroControls: false,
  minHeight: 200.0,
  minWidth: 200.0,
  baseColor: 0xffffff,
  backgroundColor: 0x2d2d2d,
  THREE,
})
```

Update 2:

I managed to fix the problem with not finding the #landing element by exporting a function that initializes the effect and running it from the mounted() and passing the element reference.

```
/*effect.js*/
const vantaEffect = (elementRef) => {
  return window.VANTA.HALO({
    el: elementRef,
    mouseControls: true,
    touchControls: true,
    gyroControls: false,
    minHeight: 200.0,
    minWidth: 200.0,
    THREE: THREE,
  })
}

export default vantaEffect
```

Now this error shows up:

```
[VANTA] Init error TypeError: Cannot read property 'LinearFilter' of undefined
```

Comment: I tried and failed :(, obviously needs to be client-only, but it also does not look like THREE is being passed properly despite passing it.. https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-margulis-5wrbv?file=/pages/index.vue is erroring out on [VANTA] Init error TypeError: Cannot read property 'LinearFilter' of undefined, which it defined just fine.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I also found this [issue on the vanta repo](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/issues/18) that is using static vanta and three .js files, but I can't get it to work either.

Comment: did you try to put it in an `if(process.client) {  }` statement block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I fiddled a bit with the sandbox that Lawrence provided, and I was able to make it work like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-thunder-pffsq

Basically what happens is that Vanta assumes that THREE is set on `window`, which doesn't happen when we import it from npm. So you must import Vanta after you import THREE and set it as a window variable.

```js
import * as THREE from "three";
// import HALO from "vanta/dist/vanta.halo.min";

export default {
  async mounted() {
    // window is only avaiable on browser
    if (process.browser) {
      window.THREE = THREE;
      const { default: HALO } = await import("vanta/dist/vanta.halo.min");
      HALO({
        el: "#abc",
        mouseControls: true,
        touchControls: true,
        minHeight: 200.0,
        minWidth: 200.0,
        xOffset: -0.17,
        size: 2.1,
        THREE: window.THREE
      });
    }
  }
};
```